# mysql query: How can I group by only cpm.ad_id and having the SUM of all cc?

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I have two tables - `cpm`(`cc`, `ad_id` and `cpm`) and `clicks`(`cc` and `ad_id`).

When I run:

```
   SELECT cpm.ad_id, 
          COUNT(clicks.id) * cpm.cpm AS clicks_income     
     FROM cpm 
LEFT JOIN clicks on clicks.ad_id = cpm.ad_id and clicks.cc = cpm.cc
 GROUP BY cpm.ad_id, cpm.cc
```

I get:

```
ad_id | clicks_income
---------------------
1     | 271.00
1     | 2.60
2     | 238.00
```

now the result I want is:

```
ad_id | clicks_income
---------------------
1     | 273.60
2     | 238.00
```

How can I group by only `cpm`.`ad_id` and having the SUM of all `cc`?

When I remove the `cpm`.`cc` I get:

```
ad_id | clicks_income
---------------------
1     | 273.00
2     | 238.00
```

Comment: Don't you just want to group by ad_id, not cc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `COUNT(whatever) * acolumn`, use `SUM(AColumn)` instead.
Also a `LEFT JOIN` doesn't make sense here because a mismatch will just add `NULL` to the sum, which isn't very helpful.

```
SELECT cpm.ad_id, SUM(cpm.cpm) AS clicks_income 
FROM cpm INNER JOIN clicks ON clicks.ad_id = cpm.ad_id AND clicks.cc = cpm.cc
GROUP BY cpm.ad_id
```

Comment: @yonathan garti, I made exactly the same error when starting with MySQL and it took me forever to debug.

Comment: you know after little playing with this query i found that SUM(cpm.cpm) is what make the diffrence. but i can't understend the logic. i mean how mysql know that i meant to sum all the clicks count vs the cpm. can you please point me to a good article in this subject. and thanks agin.

Comment: @yonathan, try the query with and without the group by and see if you can spot how it works

Comment: Also notice those double rows you got in the first query in the question, those got added in the calculations as well giving the wrong result.

Comment: nice, i think i got it. thanks. but i will need more practice

Comment: @Yonathan, for a primer on SQL joins see: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT cpm.ad_id, COUNT(clicks.id)*cpm.cpm AS clicks_income 
FROM cpm LEFT JOIN clicks ON clicks.ad_id = cpm.ad_id AND clicks.cc = cpm.cc
GROUP BY cpm.ad_id
```

Comment: @yonathan: Please write comments, rather than adding feedback into someone else's answer by editing.

Comment: when i removing the group by `cc` the clicks_income is not correct see my edit ^